# how to match by regex "to" in url?

Tags: java, regex

I have this url

```
http://host.com/routingRequest?returnJSON=true&timeout=60000&to=s%3A73746647+d%3Afalse+f%3A-1.0+x%3A-74.454383+y%3A40.843021+r%3A-1.0+cd%3A-1.0+fn%3A-1+tn%3A-1+bd%3Atrue+st%3ACampus%7EDr&returnGeometries=true&nPaths=1&returnClientIds=true&returnInstructions=true
&hour=12+00&from=s%3A-1+d%3Afalse+f%3A-1.0+x%3A-74.241765+y%3A40.830182+r%3A-1.0+cd%3A-1.0+fn%3A56481485+tn%3A26459042+bd%3Afalse+st%3AClaremont%7EAve&sameResultType=true&type=HISTORIC_TIME
```

and i try to fetch

```
to = -74.454383, 40.843021
from = -74.241765, 40.830182
hour = 12+00
```

with this code:

```
    String patternString = "(x%3A) (.+?) (y%3A) (.+?) (r%3A)";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(freshResponse.regression_requestUrl);

    H4 h4 = new H4().appendText("Response ID: " + id);
    Ul ul = new Ul();
    Li li1 = new Li();
    Li li2 = new Li();
    if (matcher.find()) {
        li1.appendText("From: " + matcher.group(1) + ", " + matcher.group(2));
    }
    if (matcher.find()) {
        li2.appendText("To: " + matcher.group(1) + ", " + matcher.group(2));
    }

    patternString = "(&hour=) (.+?) (&from=)";
    pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
    matcher = pattern.matcher(freshResponse.regression_requestUrl);

    Li li3 = new Li();
    if (matcher.find()) {
        li3.appendText("At: " + matcher.group(1));
    }
```

but i get no matches. what am i missing?

could I have done this without regex more easily?

Comment: You should use `URI` instead, and `.getQuery()`; it will be much easier to extract what you want afterwards

Comment: Don't do it.  "Parsing" raw URLs with regexes is going to give you horrible problems with edge cases, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Map params = new HashMap();
String url = "http://host.com/routingRequest?returnJSON=true&timeout=60000&to=s%3A73746647+d%3Afalse+f%3A-1.0+x%3A-74.454383+y%3A40.843021+r%3A-1.0+cd%3A-1.0+fn%3A-1+tn%3A-1+bd%3Atrue+st%3ACampus%7EDr&returnGeometries=true&nPaths=1&returnClientIds=true&returnInstructions=true
&hour=12+00&from=s%3A-1+d%3Afalse+f%3A-1.0+x%3A-74.241765+y%3A40.830182+r%3A-1.0+cd%3A-1.0+fn%3A56481485+tn%3A26459042+bd%3Afalse+st%3AClaremont%7EAve&sameResultType=true&type=HISTORIC_TIME";
List<NameValuePair> params = URLEncodedUtils.parse(new URI(url), "UTF-8");

for (NameValuePair param : params) {
  map.put(param.getName(),param.getValue());
}
```

You need to use [apache httpclient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html) to get the NameValuePair class.